# Create custom headers in zend soap server WSDL

Tags: soap, esb, zend-soap

Is there a way of creating an WSDL custom header with the auto-discovery function zend-soap server? Or an other alternative way of managing such a request on the soap server?

I need to process a request coming from an ESB proxy containing a soapenv:header like this one:

```
<soapenv:Header>
     <esb:header>
        <esb:message_type>AddNewOrder</esb:message_type>
        <esb:version>01.80</esb:version>
        <esb:source_entity>LPRO</esb:source_entity>
        <esb:source_application>NOLS</esb:source_application>
        <esb:destination_entity>LPRO</esb:destination_entity>
        <esb:destination_application>TIRE</esb:destination_application><esb:message_id>414d51204750455342333332202020201581675c22c0e127</esb:message_id><esb:correl_message_id>414d51204750455342333332202020201581675c22c13403</esb:correl_message_id><esb:message_id>X&apos;414d51204750455342333332202020201581675c22c13403&apos;</esb:message_id>
     </esb:header>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?